Yahoo Finance Python API doesn't return the list of options for a symbol
Something has change recently with Yahoo finance Python API stock.options - this object is empty. It was working fine at the end of 2023 and I tried it a month ago with this problem. I used commonly traded symbols like QQQ or MSFT. Can anyone help getting around this issue please. My yfinance version is 0.2.37
Upgraded to the latest yfinance - no change.
Here is the sample code:
import yfinance as yf

stock = yf.Ticker('MSFT') 
options = stock.options 
print("options: ", options) # this prints empty results


Hi, your code worked for me with yfinance-0.2.40 and python3.10. options:  ('2024-05-24', '2024-05-31', '2024-06-07',

Unfortunately this is not an official Yahoo library, and Yahoo is blocking the package from time to time. Despite that community tries to bypass blocks and make it workable again. All this means that old versions of yfinance won't work. You always need to keep the latest version.

Thank you, Johnny. I'm using python 3.11.3, wondering if there is an issue with this version. Will try 3.10

Strangely, after switching to 3.10.9, I'm still getting an empty list of options. I added  print(sys.version) to the code above and here is my printout:
3.10.9 (main, Mar  1 2023, 12:20:14) [Clang 14.0.6 ]
options:  ()

could you print print(yf.__version__). Also check your vpn/proxy settings. Maybe the issue is in it.

If yf is 0.2.40 then also add yf.enable_debug_mode() in the beggining of your code and please add output to the question.

after switching to python3.10 somehow it was picking up an older version of yf. Once I made sure I'm using yf 0.2.40 the issue was gone. Johnny Cheesecutter,
Thank you for your help!!
